# SSIS logging is not recording package level errors

Tags: ssis

I have configured SSIS logging to write errors to file. Under Details section I have check marked only the OnError as shown in screenshot below.

Task level errors get logged, but the package level error do not get logged. So I have to open the execution report in SQL management studio to check the error. What could be the issue?

[image]

Comment: did you check the box for the package from the logging configuration?

Comment: yes I have just put a screenshot to show this

Comment: i think the error info from the task will be propagated to the package. Which error would you like to see? do you have any custom message?

Comment: On the execution report, under "All messages" I can see errors recorded against the dataflow task. But the main error message that actually helps me to resolve the issue is recorded against the Package. But this package error doesn't appear in my logs.